# Remove all numbers which are lower than 15 using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to remove numbers which are lower than '15' using preg_replace for example:
`$string = '1 20 5 16 11 15 14';`

I'm expecting the output after preg_replace to be `20 16 15`

How can I do that?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. Then we'll try to improve on it

Comment: Why do you think a regex is the only answer? if it's a space-separated list of numbers, why not `array_filter` + `explode(' ', $string);` and only return numbers >= 15?

Comment: It is easier to pull out the numbers >= 15 and create a new string, than to remove all the numbers less than 15.

Answer (score 1):

use this pattern

```
\s*\b\d\b|\b1[01234]\b
```

Explanation

```
\s          # <whitespace character>
*           # (zero or more)(greedy)
\b          # <word boundary>
\d          # <digit 0-9>
\b          # <word boundary>
|           # OR
\b          # <word boundary>
1           # "1"
[01234]     # Character in [01234] Character Class
\b          # <word boundary>
```

Comment: @alpha bravo Don't mind me but if I want the number to be 20 for example what should I change ? :3

Answer (score 0):

Replacing all numbers which are in range from `0` to `9` or in range from `10` to `14`

```
$string = '1 20 5 16 11 15 14';
var_dump(preg_replace("/\b([0-9]{1}|1[0-4]{1})\b/", "", $string));

// the output: ' 20  16  15 '
```

Comment: The `{1}`'s are not beneficial.